# Build OpenSSL with Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gcc, openssl

Apple has removed llvm-gcc from Xcode 5 so I don't know what compiler to use to build OpenSSL.

There's gcc in iPhoneSimulator.platform direcory but no gcc in iPhoneOS.platform

So the error I'm getting is

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc: No such file or directory

How do I build OpenSSL in Xcode 5?

Comment: See https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone

Comment: @rmaddy please reply as an answer an I'll mark it as accepted.